# How to cancel VLAN FireWall by rest api

Tags: rest, api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I do not know How to cancel **VLAN FireWall** by rest api.
There was nothing like **deleteObject** method of **SoftLayer_Network_Vlan** or **SoftLayer_Network_Vlan_Firewall** service.

So, Please tell me how to  cancel **VLAN FireWall** by rest api.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recomed you to read this article:

https://sldn.softlayer.com/node/274103 (Getting started with REST and the SoftLayer Billing API)

Basically you need to camcel the associated billingItem of your VLAN for that you can use the https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Billing_Item/cancelService or the https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Billing_Item/cancelItem methods

Comment: Thank you so much. I have one more question. Do you know how to get  vlan_firewall_id ?

Comment: you need to call this method https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkVlans plus this objectmask mask[firewallNetworkComponents,
                networkVlanFirewall,
                dedicatedFirewallFlag,
                firewallGuestNetworkComponents,
                firewallInterfaces,
                firewallRules,
                highAvailabilityFirewallFlag]

Comment: see this article about the use of objectMask and REST https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/rest

Comment: maybe this documentation about firewals can help you as well https://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/phil/getting-started-firewalls